# Rounding a float to the nearest .5

Tags: ios, rounding

I need to round a float to the nearest .5, for example:

```
1.1 = 1
1.5 = 1.5
1.6 = 1.5
1.8 = 2
```

and so on.
I really don't know how to do it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Nearest 0.5, not 5, but I guess the link is close enough.

Comment: your third example, if rounded to the nearest .5, would be 1.5 not 2. Do you really mean round?

Comment: @PeteH you're right, I'll correct the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For positive numbers Multiply by 2, add 0.5, truncate, divide by 2.

Comment: You are a godsend sir